# Property not found Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm receiving this error on Symfony 2.7.9:

> Neither the property "puestos" nor one of the methods "addPuesto()"/"removePuesto()", "setPuestos()", "puestos()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador".

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuario_trabajador")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "UserBundle\Entity\Usuario", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "UserBundle\Entity\Usuario", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 * 
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = {"nit","dpi"}, targetClass = "UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador", message="El dpi o nit debe ser único")
 * Esta entidad cubre los tipos de Asistente, Supervisor y Gerente.
 *
 * @author  Pablo Díaz soporte@newtonlabs.com.gt
 */
class UsuarioTrabajador extends Usuario
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="direccion",type="string",length=255)
     */
    private $direccion;

    /**
     * @var date fecha de egreso de la empresa.
     * @ORM\Column(name="fechaEgreso", type="date",nullable=true)
     */
    private $fechaEgreso;

    /**
     * @var string DPI del trabajador
     * @ORM\Column(name="dpi",type="string",length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $dpi;

    /**
     * Número de identificación tributaria.
     *
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="nit", type="string",length=20,unique=true)
     */
    private $nit;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="telefono", type="string",length=15,nullable=true)
     */
    private $telefono;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DatosPrestaciones", mappedBy="usuario")
     */
    private $datosPrestaciones;

    /**
     * @var  string Tipo de Usuarios(Asistente, Supervisor, Gerente)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Puesto", mappedBy="usuarioPuesto")
     */
    private $puestos;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->datosPrestaciones = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->puestos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set direccion
     *
     * @param string $direccion
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function setDireccion($direccion)
    {
        $this->direccion = $direccion;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get direccion
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDireccion()
    {
        return $this->direccion;
    }

    /**
     * Set fechaEgreso
     *
     * @param \DateTime $fechaEgreso
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function setFechaEgreso($fechaEgreso)
    {
        $this->fechaEgreso = $fechaEgreso;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fechaEgreso
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getFechaEgreso()
    {
        return $this->fechaEgreso;
    }

    /**
     * Set dpi
     *
     * @param string $dpi
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function setDpi($dpi)
    {
        $this->dpi = $dpi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dpi
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDpi()
    {
        return $this->dpi;
    }

    /**
     * Set nit
     *
     * @param string $nit
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function setNit($nit)
    {
        $this->nit = $nit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nit
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNit()
    {
        return $this->nit;
    }

    /**
     * Set telefono
     *
     * @param string $telefono
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function setTelefono($telefono)
    {
        $this->telefono = $telefono;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telefono
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTelefono()
    {
        return $this->telefono;
    }

    /**
     * Add datosPrestacione
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\DatosPrestaciones $datosPrestacione
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function addDatosPrestacione(\UserBundle\Entity\DatosPrestaciones $datosPrestacione)
    {
        $this->datosPrestaciones[] = $datosPrestacione;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove datosPrestacione
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\DatosPrestaciones $datosPrestacione
     */
    public function removeDatosPrestacione(\UserBundle\Entity\DatosPrestaciones $datosPrestacione)
    {
        $this->datosPrestaciones->removeElement($datosPrestacione);
    }

    /**
     * Get datosPrestaciones
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getDatosPrestaciones()
    {
        return $this->datosPrestaciones;
    }

    /**
     * Add puesto
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Puesto $puesto
     *
     * @return UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function addPuesto(\UserBundle\Entity\Puesto $puesto)
    {
        $this->puestos[] = $puesto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove puesto
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Puesto $puesto
     */
    public function removePuesto(\UserBundle\Entity\Puesto $puesto)
    {
        $this->puestos->removeElement($puesto);
    }

    /**
     * Get puestos
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPuestos()
    {
        return $this->puestos;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->nombre.' '.$this->apellidos;
    }
}
```

This is the other Entity

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Puesto
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Puesto
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var  string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tipoPuesto",type="string",length=100)
     */
    private $tipoPuesto;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombrePuesto", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombrePuesto;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador", inversedBy="puestos")
     * @var [type]
     */
    private $usuarioPuesto;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombrePuesto
     *
     * @param string $nombrePuesto
     *
     * @return Puesto
     */
    public function setNombrePuesto($nombrePuesto)
    {
        $this->nombrePuesto = $nombrePuesto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombrePuesto
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombrePuesto()
    {
        return $this->nombrePuesto;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return Puesto
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set usuario
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajdor $usuario
     *
     * @return Puesto
     */
    public function setUsuario(\UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajdor $usuario = null)
    {
        $this->usuario = $usuario;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get usuario
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajdor
     */
    public function getUsuario()
    {
        return $this->usuario;
    }

    /**
     * Set tipoPuesto
     *
     * @param string $tipoPuesto
     *
     * @return Puesto
     */
    public function setTipoPuesto($tipoPuesto)
    {
        $this->tipoPuesto = $tipoPuesto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tipoPuesto
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTipoPuesto()
    {
        return $this->tipoPuesto;
    }

    /**
     * Mostrar el noombre del puesto
     * @return string 
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->tipoPuesto.': '.$this->nombrePuesto.' '.$this->getUsuarioPuesto();
    }

    /**
     * Set usuarioPuesto
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador $usuarioPuesto
     *
     * @return Puesto
     */
    public function setUsuarioPuesto(\UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador $usuarioPuesto = null)
    {
        $this->usuarioPuesto = $usuarioPuesto;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get usuarioPuesto
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\UsuarioTrabajador
     */
    public function getUsuarioPuesto()
    {
        return $this->usuarioPuesto;
    }
}
```

This is the Form

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

class RegistrationTrabajadorFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // agregar campos personalizados
        $builder->add('nombre', null, [
                'label' => 'Nombre/s',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Nombre/s',
                    'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                ],

            ])
            ->add('apellidos', null, [
                'label' => 'Apellidos/s',
                'attr' => [
                        'placeholder' => 'Apellidos',
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                    ],
                ])
            ->add('username', null, [
                    'label' => 'Usuario',
                    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Nombre de Usuario',
                    ],
                ])
            ->add('email', 'email', [
                    'label' => 'Correo',
                    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                    'required' => true,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Correo electrónico',
                    ],
                ])

            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', [
                'label' => 'Contraseña',
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => ['translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'],
                'first_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Contraseña',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Contraseña',
                    ],
                ],
                'second_options' => [
                    'label' => 'Repetir Contraseña',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Repetir Contraseña',
                    ],
                ],
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',

            ])
                ->add('direccion',null,[
                    'label' => 'Dirección',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Dirección',
                    ],
                    'required' => true,
                ])
               ->add('dpi', null, [
                    'label' => 'DPI',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                         'placeholder' => 'Documento Personal de Identificación',
                    ],
                    'required' => true,

                ])
               ->add('nit', null, [
                    'label' => 'NIT',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Número de Identificación Tributaria',
                    ],
                    'required' => true,

                ])
                ->add('telefono', null, [
                    'label' => 'Teléfono',
                    'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
                        'placeholder' => 'Teléfono',
                    ],
                    'required' => false,
                ])
                ->add('submit', 'submit', [
                    'label' => 'Guardar',
                    'attr' => [
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        ],
                ])
               ->add('puestos', 'entity', [
                    'label' => false,
                    'empty_value' => 'Aquí aparecerá su puesto',
                    'class' => 'UserBundle:Puesto',
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'select2',
                        ],
                ])
            ; 
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'validation' => ['registration'],
        ]);
    }
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I have tried clearing the cache

Comment: Form type entity is for one object not an array of objects like puestos.

Comment: How do I fix it? @Cerad

Comment: If puestos needs to be an array then you need a form collection. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html